# OSMdroid GPS enable/disable user popup

Tags: android, osmdroid, android-gps

I wanted to make sure that if the user had their GPS Location off at the start of the app a popup would appear and redirect you to the location where you could toggle the GPS Location on. 
I am able to do that but as soon as I go back to my app it does no longer center in my location unless i close the app and start it again.
**What am i doing wrong?**

```
private boolean hasPermissions(){
    return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}
```

In the onCreate :

```
if (hasPermissions()) {
        setMap();
        initMyLocation();
        centerButton();
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1);
    }
```

The setMap, initMyLocation, centerButton methods:

```
public void setMap(){
    map = findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    map.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
    map.setTilesScaledToDpi(true);
    map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    map.setMultiTouchControls(true);

}
 public void initMyLocation(){

    final LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    if(!lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) || !lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)){
        //Build the alert dialog
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Something.");
        builder.setMessage("activate GPS.");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        Dialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        alertDialog.show();


    }

    GpsMyLocationProvider provider = new GpsMyLocationProvider(getApplicationContext());

    provider.addLocationSource(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    provider.addLocationSource(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    locationNewOverlay = new MyLocationNewOverlay(provider, map);
    locationNewOverlay.enableMyLocation();

    map.getOverlays().add(locationNewOverlay);


}
public void centerButton() {
    ImageButton btCenterMap = this.findViewById(R.id.menu_mylocation);
    btCenterMap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            locationNewOverlay.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    myLocation = locationNewOverlay.getMyLocation();
                }
            });
            locationNewOverlay.enableFollowLocation();

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your logic needs to be something like this:

Check Method - check for permissions and whether or not GPS/Network Location is available

- If permissions check fails, ask for permissions. On success, run the check method again
- If gps check fails, redirect to the settings page
- if both are yes, create a location overlay and add it to the map

On resume

- run the checks method

On Pause

- destroy the my location overlay, remove it from the map

Comment: It was indeed my logic that was flawed. After following your tips i got it to work. Thanks a lot!!